# Static Route-Router Only Accepts 192.168.0.1 For Default Gateway

Tags: networking, router, ip, home-networking, static-routes

I recently got a new printer, and it has Wi-Fi only, no ethernet. So, I want to set up a static route, so I do not have to deal with it changing IP addresses after each DHCP renewal potentially. I printed out the network sheet provided by my printer after setting up my printer and input the sub netmask and IP address into my router for the static route

I also tried to enter the default gateway address listed on the sheet of `192.168.1.1`, but it gave an error saying incorrect gateway address. It's a linksy router. The printer is using DHCP, not a static IP. I use `192.168.1.1` to access my router, when using the `ipconfig /all` command on my computer, it also says the default gateway is `192.168.1.1`.

Everything is telling me that my default gateway is `192.168.1.1` but my router is saying that is incorrect. When I ping `192.168.1.1`, I get a response back as I expect, but if ping `192.168.0.1`, I do not get a response back, the address my router accepts in the static route.

I am very confused on why `192.168.0.1` worked, but not what everything else is telling me. ChatGPT was the one who said to try `192.168.0.1` but couldn't answer to me why that worked even though I am 99% sure my default gateway is `192.168.1.1`.

I couldn't find anything with a Google Search on this specifically. Can someone explain this to me?

What other information do people need? Also, there is no ip conflicts as I checked that.

Here is the network diagram:

[image]

Comment: “Chat gbt was the one who said…” You meaning ChatGPT? You asked ChatGPT how to set up your router? That’s where you went wrong.

Comment: You're confusing an static IP with a static route, and we don't really have much information about your network. What do you mean by sheet? Something like ipconfig output (for windows) or its equivilent would be useful here

Comment: I ask chatgpt for clarity and it doesnt get everything wrong. So your comment Giacomo is not helpful. For Journeyman Geek, the sheet is the network sheet printed out by my printer and no i am not confusing a static ip with a static route. The printer is using dhcp, not a static ip. I set a static route after.

Comment: Why's the printer on a different subnet?  And "I  do not have to deal with it changing IP addresses after each DHCP renewal potentially" is when you set a different IP, unless you have a second router on a different subnet?

Comment: I'd also suggest - and it helps a lot 'mapping' out your network - https://superuser.com/questions/1770448/cannot-access-smb-fileshare-from-pc-in-different-subnet something like what I did here, so someone else can visualise how things look like. Even hand drawn helps a lot. And ignore chatgpt, its garbage

Comment: The printer is not on a different subnet, the printer subnet is 255.255.255.0 and the router is 255.255.255.0. The DHCP server does automatic assignment of ip address to devices on network after a certain period of time (renew cycle). The dhcp server is the dynamic host configuration protocal. I am setting a static route so that it used my route instead of the dhcp address assignment. Your comment about mapping out my network is valid though and I will go ahead and make on and put that into my question. That does help clarify exactly what people want from me with regards to clarity.

Comment: You can do static IPs with DHCP - in the example I gave, I have a mix of static and dynamic IPs on either subnet - the static route is *between* the two subnets. Also, practically with most consumer equipment, even DHCP assigned IPs change rarely, so it might be less of an issue than you think

Comment: I have added a link with an hand drawn diagram of my network for you. I am doing a static route, the dhcp i think is with my router since this is internal network, so a static route is how I do static ip with dhcp, that is what is am effectively doing.

Comment: You don't need a static route for a static IP. UNLESS your AP's running a DHCP server and on another range

Comment: You are conflating _subnets_ and _subnet **masks**_.  192.168.1.* and 192.168.0.* are different subnets, though both have a mask of 255.255.255.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The printer is not on a different subnet, the printer subnet is 255.255.255.0 and the router is 255.255.255.0.

Those are **not subnets.** They're subnet *masks,* which define only the size of a subnet but not its identity. For example, 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 and 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 are two very different subnets even if they both are of the same size.

But if the printer is, in fact, *not* on a different subnet – if it's in the same 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 (i.e. 192.168.1.0/24) as the rest of the LAN – then it makes absolutely no sense to create a static route for it. Your router already has a route for the entire subnet it's in.

> So, I want to set up a static route, so I do not have to deal with it changing IP addresses after each DHCP renewal potentially. I printed out the network sheet provided by my printer after setting up my printer and input the sub netmask and IP address into my router for the static route

A static route is really the wrong tool here.

Even if done correctly, a static route needs a static IP address to point to – and if the printer has a static IP address, well, that already solves the problem of it changing IP addresses, and you can just use that address directly *without* dealing without custom routes.

Besides that, your router will probably have an easier option of setting up static DHCP lease assignments – DHCP does not imply "changing addresses after each renewal"; the printer's address will be exactly what the router tells the device it will be.

> Everything is telling me that my default gateway is 192.168.1.1 but my router is saying that is incorrect. When I ping 192.168.1.1, I get a response back as I expect, but if ping 192.168.0.1, I do not get a response back, the address my router accepts in the static route.

The router is saying it's "incorrect" because that's the router's **own** address in your case.

The 'gateway' field isn't a magic parameter that needs to be discovered via divination – it's literally just the IP address of whatever router you want the device to pass the packets on to; if you know that packets must go via 192.168.1.1 next, then you specify 192.168.1.1 as the gateway, and if you know that there's no device having the IP address 192.168.7.7, then that automatically means 192.168.7.7 can't possibly be a valid gateway either.

This also means that the "correct" value is not universal across the entire network but **depends on where it is being used**; for example, devices connected to router A would use A as their gateway, but A itself would need to use router B or C as its gateway, and so on – it doesn't make sense for router A to use "router A" as its own gateway. So it is correct that 192.168.1.1 is the default gateway in one part of your network, but that doesn't carry over here.

Actually, right now, there is actually *no* valid value that you could enter here for a static route, because your network currently doesn't even have a second router that you'd forward those packets to. You can tell this by looking around and determining that you don't have any routers other than the one you're configuring.

In this setup, even if the printer's IP address was indeed in a different subnet numerically, it's still attached to same "link" as the main subnet topologically, so what you would want is a route *without* a gateway specified – a "link route" or "interface route". (Sometimes a router might insist on 0.0.0.0 as the "gateway" for such routes, but really it's a route without a gateway.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that I need to go back and learn more about static route, routing tables, and subnetting. What i wanted is actually to set up a static ip like you said and I do this by a dhcp reservation I think its called. So I will eliminate that static route I setup since that is pointless being there. I clearly do not understand some things like I thought.